# Bash getting and parsing results

Tags: bash, parsing

I am trying to parse some results of

```
arp -a
```

and

```
Michael$ arp -a
? (10.254.0.1) at 0:1e:c9:bb:95:8c on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.254.0.2) at 0:1e:c9:bb:9a:8c on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.254.0.3) at 0:1e:c9:bb:9d:8c on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

How would I run a bash script to run arp -a and print out the IP for each returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
arp -a | cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

If you don't want the parenthesis:

```
arp -a | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | sed 's/[()]//g'
```

Or, to dump the ip addresses collected into an array:

```
ips=( $(arp -a | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | sed -r -e 's/[()]//g') )
```

To access:

```
echo ${ips[1]}
```

Answer (score 3):

For GNU `grep` (and some others which support PCRE):

```
arp -a | grep -Po '.*?\(\K.*?(?=\).*)'
```

AWK:

```
arp -a | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}'
```

`sed`:

```
arp -a | sed 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/'
```

Perl:

```
arp -a | perl -lne 'print $1 if m{.*?\(\K(.*?)(?=\).*)}'
```

Comment: How would I just take the first one and store the IP in a variable?

Comment: @Michael: You didn't have that as part of your question. `var=$(arp -a | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2; exit}'` would be one way.

Comment: Oops, there should be a closing parenthesis at the end of that: `var=$(arp -a | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2; exit}')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using awk:

```
arp -a | awk '{ gsub(/[()]/, "", $2); print $2; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash:

```
arp -a  | while read -a line ; do
  echo ${line[1]:1:-1}
done
```